# MATLAB h5write has inconsistent performance

Tags: matlab, hdf5

I'm trying to use the [savefast](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39721-save-mat-files-more-quickly/content/savefast.m) function on the MATLAB FileExchange.  I noticed that it's performance on my setup is not consistent.  When I run the below code, I get the below times.  Notice on the 4th run it took 20x longer!  There are generally between 2 and 5 slow runs per 10, randomly distributed (sometimes 3 in a row will be slow).  The variation is entirely in the low level H5ML.hdf5lib2 function.

I've tried it on 4 different machines.  On 2 of them (Server 2008 R2, Windows 7), I see the wild variation  below.  On 2 others (Server 2008, Server 2012), there is almost no variation.  The 2 Server 2008 boxes have identical hardware, anti-virus, and almost nothing running on them.  So the problem is very machine specific.  However, all boxes are relatively powerful 64-bit so I think this problem should not be happening.  Is there some tricky low level setting to make HDF5 work more consistently?

When I try using the `save` or `fwrite` command instead of the code below, times have little variation which makes me think it is an HDF5 specific issue.

```
clear classes;
delete('test_*.mat');
x = rand(10000, 1000);
%%
disp('Using h5write:');
for j = 1:10
    % make new file
    fname = sprintf('test_h5_%d.mat', j);
    dummy = 0;
    save(fname, '-v7.3', 'dummy');
    varname = '/x';
    h5create(fname, varname, size(x), 'DataType', class(x));
    tic;
    h5write(fname, varname, x);
    toc;
end

disp('Using save:');
for j = 1:10
    tic;
    fname = sprintf('test_save_%d.mat', j);
    save(fname, 'x');
    toc;
end

disp('Using fwrite:');
for j = 1:10
    tic;
    fname = sprintf('test_fwrite_%d.mat', j);
    fileID = fopen(fname,'w');
    fwrite(fileID, x, 'double');
    fclose(fileID);
    toc;
end

disp('Using memory map:');
for j = 1:10
    tic;
    fname = sprintf('test_fwrite_%d.mat', j);
    m = memmapfile(fname, ...
        'Format','double');
    m.Writable = true;
    m.Data = x;
    toc;
end
clear m;
```

Output of above code:

```
>> 
Using h5write:
Elapsed time is 0.120691 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.123445 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.109917 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.773781 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.104730 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.115631 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.106282 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.119643 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.109200 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.110083 seconds.
Using save:
Elapsed time is 2.774994 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.776656 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.777405 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.811365 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.780027 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.775661 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.776308 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.800510 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.783472 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.782114 seconds.
Using fwrite:
Elapsed time is 0.035606 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.094308 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.033619 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.034147 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.033776 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.034627 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.033806 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.035084 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.034562 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.039331 seconds.
Using memory map:
Elapsed time is 0.079036 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.035585 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.035654 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.036398 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.035054 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.039047 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.036286 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.035016 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.036145 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.036497 seconds.
```

Output of ver command:

```
>> ver
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB Version: 8.2.0.701 (R2013b)
MATLAB License Number: xxxxxx
Operating System: Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
Java Version: Java 1.7.0_11-b21 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB                                                Version 8.2        (R2013b)
Database Toolbox                                      Version 5.0        (R2013b)
Statistics Toolbox                                    Version 8.3        (R2013b)
```

**UPDATE:**
I've tried:

1. Rebooting the box.
2. I have an identical box (h/w, os) that this problem does not occur on.  I killed any processes that were on the slow box that were not on the normal box.  It did not make a difference.
3. When I change the data to be random, it makes no difference.
4. When I use the save command instead, times are consistent.  This makes me think it is not a general disk issue, but something about the setup and hdf5.

Comment: Do you have an antivirus, indexing, or any other I/O intensive process that is running on one machine but not the other?

Comment: Okay, very weird.  I just tried another box identical in specs (h/w, os, antivirus) to the one I show the results from.  The problem does not occur!  So it is something very specific to the box.  Hmmmm...

Comment: Does a restart help?

Comment: Is it always the 5th and 9th?  I would put that in a loop say 100 times and check that it always is the same 2.  Are you always starting with a clean directory such that test#.mat does not exist?

Comment: It is random, not always the particular ones.  Sometimes it's 3 in a row.  It's almost always between 2 and 5 that are slow.  It can be 10x to 50x slower.  Clean directory does not make a difference.

Comment: Could you try some HDD benchmark on both systems? Might be that writing to HDD is slow for some reason, but due to buffering it takes some iterations until Matlab slows down.

Comment: Try writing to a Memory Mapped file instead of the HDD.  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/overview-of-memory-mapping.html this will tell you if it's the hard drive or not.  If you're familiar with Linux this is like using /dev/shm/

Comment: Benchmarking using ATTO shows very similar results on both boxes.